# How can I teach my child about Christianity?

Tags: development, religion

I am a Christian myself but my husband is not. I would like to teach my child about my religion and I have been thinking of ordering books from online Christian bookstores.  Is this the best option?  Which other methods can I use? Do you think children would enjoy Christian-themed toys and games?

Comment: The information in [this question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/how-do-you-teach-a-child-religious-views?rq=1) may be helpful to you. Note that "is this a good website to shop from?" is not on topic for our community, which is why another user edited your post.

Comment: "I would like to teach my child about my religion" = at that point, it's really just a personal decision you'll have to make on your own.

Comment: As DA01 says, it is a personal decision.  However, considering your husband is not a Christian, I **strongly** suggest you discuss it with him, rather than just decide on your own how you plan on teaching your child about your religion.

Comment: This user has only posted two things on this site.  Both are spam ads for the same website.  Please remove this question.

Comment: uh, yea, gotta second Charles. This is a spammer from the looks of it.

Comment: @Charles The links in this question were to a different website than the links in the OP's other post.  Were there other links to the same website that I missed?

Comment: @Beofett There was a link I removed to another Christian website from Zaire.  It seems awfully suspicious that this person should link to three distinct Christian .za stores completely out of context.

Comment: @Beofett apparently, .za is South Africa.  It still smells like spam to me.

Comment: @Charles I agree it smells like spam, but its possible these links may simply be part of a network the OP is familiar with and active in.  I'd rather err on the side of caution, and the links have been removed. Given the possible spam is no longer an issue, I think it is preferable to leave the community votes to handle this, rather than step in and use moderator powers.

Comment: I see this as a shopping question and believe it needs deletion.

Comment: The links have been removed. What is left behind is a valid question that may help other people looking through this site. This should stay.

Answer (score 6):

Since you self-identify as a Christian, I will presume to give you a Christian parenting answer on a secular site.

1. You should primarily SHOW, not TELL your Christianity.  In the Epistle from James we are told, "Pure religion and undefiled in the sight of God is this: to help widows and orphans in their distress, and to keep oneself unspotted by the world."  Really, this applies to all your relationships, not just with your child.  (And actually, "show, don't tell" is probably good general advice for influencing other people, apart from religion, and even apart from parenting.)
2. You should definitely NOT undermine the father-child relationship (or the husband-wife relationship) with your Christianity.  The Apostle Paul was asked about this by the church at Corinth, and he advised Christians with non-Christian spouses to stay with them, and to win them (if possible) to Christian belief by their QUIET life of exemplary Christian behavior (as opposed to nagging and mind-games).
3. On the other hand, you have both the right and the responsibility to be open about your faith in front of your child and husband, even if that causes conflict (assuming you're not being obnoxious about it).  Again, Paul says, "If the unbeliever leaves [i.e., divorces you over your belief], then let him leave."

Regarding Christian-themed toys and games: As a general rule, children detest propaganda even more than adults.  My kids loved playing with the manger scene figures at Christmas, and they liked the Noah's ark set animals.  But they liked them because they were fun, not because they were Christian-themed.

Comment: I agree, the concepts of the toys will be completely lost on children. Show your children. Explain to them WHY you did or did not do things.  It is also written that we should remember the things God has done for us, so do not be afraid to talk about God to your children. But like dmm said, do not be obnoxious in-front of your husband. The only person who can change your husband is God.

Answer (score 4):

I think that exposure to different ideas is the best way to teach children about religions in general. The degree will be age-specific and will require commitment from parents.

This approach is applicable to practicing and non-practicing religious, and atheists alike, in my opinion.

If your intention is to guide your child to **making their own decision** then you should teach them analytic and "mental-defense" skills. Life in general, and so also religion, is littered with malcontents and those who would take advantage of you and lead you astray.

Exposure will help your children identify charlatans (religious and otherwise)

For Christianity-Specific answers, perhaps you're better served at [Christianity.SE](http://Christianity.StackExchange.Com)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to pass values to our children are those about which we are passionate our self. Are you a passionate christian? 
Yes, then do not worry, explain you child where you passion is coming from and this will do it.

Jesus was a non-violent person who thought LOVE can heal all the wrongs in this world.

If you feel this is true then you will find the right words to explain that to your own child.

Do not forget the famous christian text from the 1 Epistle to Corinthians chapter 13 ...it will inspire you: it did inspire me and I am NOT a christian.